# Making an iOS framework: including 3rd party libraries and code

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, linker

Im making a static iOS framework. I want to use 3rd party code, lets use `AFNetworking` as an example, in my framework. `AFNetworking` is popular. I can sense the namespace collisions now. What is the best practice here? As far as I understand I have 3 options:

1) Build `AFNetworking` into my framework, exporting the headers. This lets clients use the version of `AFNetworking` in my library, but they can't use other frameworks that also link `AFNetworking`. They rely on me for updates to AFNetworking if they build on it.

2) Code against the `AFNetworking` Headers, but make the third parties include `AFNetworking` in their projects. This adds an extra step for framework consumers, they have to add `AFNetworking` source. There may be version incompatibilities in the future, but at least if another framework uses `AFNetworking` they can use that at the same time.

3) Re-namespace `AFNetworking` and keep the headers private. This way I avoid namespace collisions in any way, except that it then becomes really hard to update my copy of `AFNetworking`. The final binary gets a bit bigger but all interoperability issues are resolved. This is a lot more work for me.

Do I have any other options? What are the best practices?

Comment: I don't see why you would have namespace collisions (unless you prefix your classes with `AF`). Use the latest stable version of AFNetworking, but let users include it. If the API you're using is exposed, it's unlikely to change.

Comment: Have you checked out cocoapods? You can add a dependency to other pods.

Comment: @H2CO3 If the compiled `AFNetworking` objects are included in my library binary and the user adds the code themselves or uses another framework with it included there will be namespace collisions in objective-c when the linker attempts to make the final application binary.

Comment: @jackslash But that's what I'm saying - you do **not** include the binaries of the library. Nor the headers. You require the user to do so.

Comment: I'd go with option 2). Personally, if I download a library that relies on another one, it's no big deal, it's really just a few clicks to include it. But, make sure the description file of your framework displays a warning in bold telling me I'll nedd AFNetworking. Also make sure that if I try using your library without AFNetworking, there's a **really** explicit error telling me I did not include this library. I really think as long as the user of your library is well informed, it's perfectly fine. And honestly, it will save you much time you'll be able to use to improve your own library ;)

Comment: @H2CO3 ah yes you were. One of those times when people argue the same thing ;)

Comment: @jackslash Hi, I need some help here. Suppose if I want to follow option 2 for some class files only(in my case I am using RNCryptor class files - https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-objc/tree/master/RNCryptor) what will be the process. I found that if I add the same files into sample project along with the framework which is build with those files is working fine. I am little confuse here, sorry i have little knowledge in dependency. thank you...

Comment: Thats fine until your app includes a different, API incompatible version of RNCryptor at which point the app version stomps the framework version (or vis versa, it can be non deterministic) and then you get crashes. You should post a new question for detailed help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A better option is use http://cocoapods.org. This way, is possible to declare the dependencies of the libs and the get a single download for the whole project.

Don't rename headers. Is time-consuming, and hard.

P.D: A sample of this:

http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/using-cocoapods-to-manage-private-libraries/

Comment: This does have the downside of requiring a host app to use Cocoapods.

Answer (score 0):

as far as number 3 goes, it's not a full on "re-namespace" but it's akin to that:

http://atastypixel.com/blog/avoiding-duplicate-symbol-issues-when-using-common-utilities-within-a-static-library/

Comment: Found a similar article that goes into more detail: http://pdx.esri.com/blog/namespacing-dependencies/